# error message Byref type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

here is the code

```
Dim Comp_Str, Comp_Val As String
Call Populate(Comp_Str, Comp_Val)

Sub Populate(Str As String, Tpry_Str As String)
```

This is throwing a error
Byref Argument type mismatch

I am not able to find what is the problem

Its `String` All the way

Comment: See [Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Declare the types for each variable. If you omit one then it's type is considered as Variant by default.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Comp_Str As String, Comp_Val As String
    Call Populate(Comp_Str, Comp_Val)
End Sub

Sub Populate(Str As String, Tpry_Str As String)
    ' ...
End Sub
```